# Mail open AppStore or open the App with link

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Ok, I know this question is already asked. But The question was a little bit old, so I thought maybe there are new and easier way to do this:

opening AppStore if the App isn't installed, and open the App if it is installed.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you cannot open an app other than the AppStore or Safari.
What you can do is check if the app is installed, do nothing if so, else open the AppStore:

```
-(IBAction)appCheck:(id)sender {

    NSArray *checkForApp = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               @"/Applications/YourApp.app",


    NSString *exists;
    for(NSString *string in checkForApp)
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:string])
            exists=@"y";
        else
            //OPEN APP STORE
}
```

Comment: be careful with checking for specific files in a sandbox architecture, that may well change some day and while there are some apps having multiple versions (HD,Lite,Pro...) there may be more than 1 app (more than 1 possible appname) apps serving same URL scheme, so canOpenURL could be safer in this way, either way if the URL scheme is not there there is not much you can do with it at the moment.

Comment: Since it is an Array it is always possible to add multiple app names.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't specific enough. I want to open like... the app or appstore from a link in the mail. It's like... a mail that challenges your friend to "this game".